# Limiting the number of feed items displayed

Tags: php, simplexml

Below is roughly what I am using to display items from a feed.  It works fine but the feed has many items and I want to be able to just display the first 5 items in the feed. How can this e done?

```
    <?php
    $theurl = 'http://www.theurl.com/feed.xml';


    $xml = simplexml_load_file($theurl);
    $result = $xml->xpath("/items/item");
    foreach ($result as $item) { 
    $date = $item->date;
    $title = $item->title;

    echo 'The title is '. $title.' and the date is '. $date .'';

    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($result as $i => $item) { 
    if ($i == 5) {
        break;
    }
    echo 'The title is '.$item->title.' and the date is '. $item->date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop may be more suitable for this than a `foreach` loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    echo 'The title is '.$result[$i]->title.' and the date is '. $result[$i]->date;
}
```

This loop has a much higher performance when not modifying anything in the array, so if speed matters I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as part of the XPath query:

```
<?php
$theurl = 'http://www.theurl.com/feed.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($theurl);
$result = $xml->xpath('/items/item[position() <= 5]');
foreach ($result as $item) { 
    $date = $item->date;
    $title = $item->title;

    echo 'The title is '. $title.' and the date is '. $date . '';
}
?>
```

[Here's a demo!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5fTPqj)